# The right tool for the job (3d Modeling)

Tags: 3d, xna

I am looking at xna development studio, and i like what i'v seen so far.

What tool would you recogmend for creating 3d models that i can import.

I would like the answer to be based on the following:

1. Most Important - Ease of use
2. Learning curve
3. Features
4. Compatibility with other 3d engines
5. cost

Thanx guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people are fond of [Blender](http://www.blender.org/). It's free and has a very large community.

I found it relatively easy to learn - given some prior experience with 3d. I could see it being a good tool to learn 3d modeling basics too.

As far as features, I never ran into anything I couldn't do with it. That's a very broad question. I get the impression you're a beginner, so I think it would take awhile for you to outgrow it.

It outputs nearly all common file formats, so compatibility will not likely be an issue.

Comment: thanx, good to get an opinion from someone with actual experience on the tool, this will also be a hobby for me.

Answer (score 0):

Blender is the way to go, unless you are willing the dish out a bunch of money(even so blender compares great).  Though if you are just starting off, I would recommend 2d and then go to 3d afterwards